# The portals keep teleporting me back and forth

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a simple c# script to teleport me between two portals. The problem is that when I place the portals facing down, it keeps teleporting me between them. the script works fine when it is upright. I tried to make a cooldown so that it can't teleport me over and over. I also tried to place the destination above the portal.

Here is my code:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class portal : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject portal2;
    public GameObject player;

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (player.transform.position != portal2.transform.position)
        {
            if(other.CompareTag("Player"))
            {
                player.transform.position = portal2.transform.position;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have no idea how to answer your question, but let it be known that I approve of your username.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comparing the transform positions is not likely to be useful as even a tiny amount of offset in the float (think something as small as 0.0000001 will cause the condition to fail. I would suggest that when a player portals through to another portal, that you place them slightly in front of the portal, in addition to a small cooldown that prevents portal travel. You'll need to translate the players speed (not velocity, speed) to the direction (transform.forward) of the portal they exited as well to keep them moving in the right direction.

Comment: That makes sense. As you come out of a portal on the floor, gravity will quickly suck you back in. Perhaps you need a speed multiplier property on your portal and you can make it higher on these floor portals so the player comes out of it a lot faster.